# Function in .emacs file don't overwrite the one in external file untill executed by hand

Tags: emacs, elisp, require

I've overwrite `erc-match-message` function erc-mode and I have it in my .emacs file I added additional paramter to the hook and I got this error when I run `erc`

```
error in process filter: Wrong number of arguments: (lambda (match-type
nickuserhost msg notification) (interactive) (if (and (eq match-type
(quote current-nick)) (not notification)) (progn (async-exec-command 
"mpg123 -q /home/kuba/Pobrane/beep-8.mp3") (notify "ERC" msg)))), 3
```

my hook function look like this:

```lisp
(defun mention-notify (match-type nickuserhost msg notification)
  (interactive)
  (if (and (eq match-type 'current-nick)
           (not notification))
      (progn
        (async-exec-command "mpg123 -q /home/kuba/Pobrane/beep-8.mp3")
        (notify "ERC" msg))))
```

(one extra `notification` parameter) it work when I evaluate `erc-match-message` definition using `eval-last-sexp`.

I have this

```lisp
(require 'erc)
(defun erc-match-message ()
   ;; my overwritten function that's defined in erc.el
   ...)
(defun mention-notify (match-type nickuserhost msg notification)
   ;; notify hook handler
   ...)
(defun irc ()
  "Connect to the freenode"
  (interactive)
  (erc :server "barjavel.freenode.net"
       :port 6667
       :nick "jcubic"
       :password "<PASS>"))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c i")  'irc)
```

**Why function defined in .emacs file don't overwrite the one define in external file added using require?**

Comment: Is your .emacs compiled? If so, did you re-compile after adding your hook function?

Comment: @KeithFlower No, is just .emacs, I didn't know that I can compile it. And when I change something like do error I got error when inintializting emacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`erc-match-message` is actually defined in `erc-match.el`, which probably gets loaded afterwards somehow.  Try adding `(require 'erc-match)` as well before the redefinition.

Comment: Ok it work now. but I needed to use `(setq erc-text-matched-hook` instead of `(add-hook 'erc-text-matched-hook` because erc-match have added another hook that that was throwing and error.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use `defadvice` to change the definition of a function.  It will properly handle the case you're bumping into where you change the definition even before the function is defined.

Comment: I think that it will still execute hook with 3 arguments